# Can you use xmlhttprequest.open and xmlhttprequest.send to open a new window?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I need a pop-up editor. The user chooses what to edit and the id will be sent to the new window where I'll retrieve data from a database, display the record, allow the user to update and and save the changes. When the changes are complete the window will close and the the original table is updated to show the change.

Can you use xmlhttprequest.open and xmlhttprequest.send to open a new window?

This is a sample of what I am doing and I want to be able to open the page in a new window.

```
function myfunction(date)
{
    date = document.getElementById('date').value;

    if (date == "")
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
    } 

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","want_to_open_in_new_window.php?a="+date,true);

    xmlhttp.send();   
}
```

Comment: your code is ajax, and what you need is just JavaScript to open URL in new window

Comment: The XMLHttpRequest object is used to communicate with the server to get and send data. To open a new window you don't need an ajax request. Hope that helps :).

Comment: I need a pop-up editor.  The user chooses what to edit and the id will be sent to the new window where I'll retrieve data from a database, display the record, allow the user to update and and save the changes.  When the changes are complete the window will close and the the original table is updated to show the change.

Comment: As the other comments mentioned. You do not need ajax. Just use 'window.open' to pop up a new window. And access the parent object to update the original window.

Comment: I understand how to use window.open and pass the value but how do I access the parent object to update a div?  I've only used the method above (and sending back a simple "done" message.  Not sure how I would update a table at this point (mostly because I have not got that far :D ).

Answer (score 0):

Got it

parent
window.open('editPopup.php','Edit','width=300,height=200');

popup

opener.document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = 'updated content of parent window';